# Why does MySQL's performance decrease when queries are executed in parallel?

Tags: mysql, performance, perl

**The Question**: Why MySQL performance goes down for queries joining nearly empty tables when executed in parallel?

Below is more detailed explanation of the issue I'm facing. I have two tables in MySQL

```
CREATE TABLE first (
    num int(10) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE KEY key_num (num)
) ENGINE=InnoDB

CREATE TABLE second (
    num int(10) NOT NULL,
    num2 int(10) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE KEY key_num (num, num2)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

The first one contains about a thousand records. The second one is empty or contains a very few records. It also contains double index which somehow relates to the issue: the problem goes away for single index. Now I'm trying to make a lot of identical queries to those tables in parallel. Each query looks like this:

```
SELECT first.num
FROM first
LEFT JOIN second AS second_1 ON second_1.num = -1 # non-existent key
LEFT JOIN second AS second_2 ON second_2.num = -2 # non-existent key
LEFT JOIN second AS second_3 ON second_3.num = -3 # non-existent key
LEFT JOIN second AS second_4 ON second_4.num = -4 # non-existent key
LEFT JOIN second AS second_5 ON second_5.num = -5 # non-existent key
LEFT JOIN second AS second_6 ON second_6.num = -6 # non-existent key
WHERE second_1.num IS NULL
  AND second_2.num IS NULL
  AND second_3.num IS NULL
  AND second_4.num IS NULL
  AND second_5.num IS NULL
  AND second_6.num IS NULL
```

The issue I'm getting is that instead of having a nearly linear raise in performance on 8 core machine I actually have a drop. Namely having one process, the typical number of requests per second I have is about 200. Having two processes instead of expected increase up to 300 - 400 queries per second I actually have a drop down to 150. For 10 processes I have only 70 queries per seconds. The Perl code I'm using for testing is shown below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use DBI;
use Parallel::Benchmark;
use SQL::Abstract;
use SQL::Abstract::Plugin::InsertMulti;

my $children_dbh;

foreach my $second_table_row_count (0, 1, 1000) {
    print '#' x 80, "\nsecond_table_row_count = $second_table_row_count\n";
    create_and_fill_tables(1000, $second_table_row_count);
    foreach my $concurrency (1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10, 20) {
        my $bm = Parallel::Benchmark->new(
            'benchmark' => sub {
                _run_sql();
                return 1;
            },
            'concurrency' => $concurrency,
            'time' => 3,
        );
        my $result = $bm->run();
    }
}

sub create_and_fill_tables {
    my ($first_table_row_count, $second_table_row_count) = @_;
    my $dbh = dbi_connect();
    {
        $dbh->do(q{DROP TABLE IF EXISTS first});
        $dbh->do(q{
            CREATE TABLE first (
                num int(10) NOT NULL,
                UNIQUE KEY key_num (num)
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB
        });
        if ($first_table_row_count) {
            my ($stmt, @bind) = SQL::Abstract->new()->insert_multi(
                'first',
                ['num'],
                [map {[$_]} 1 .. $first_table_row_count],
            );
            $dbh->do($stmt, undef, @bind);
        }
    }
    {
        $dbh->do(q{DROP TABLE IF EXISTS second});
        $dbh->do(q{
            CREATE TABLE second (
                num int(10) NOT NULL,
                num2 int(10) NOT NULL,
                UNIQUE KEY key_num (num, num2)
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB
        });
        if ($second_table_row_count) {
            my ($stmt, @bind) = SQL::Abstract->new()->insert_multi(
                'second',
                ['num'],
                [map {[$_]} 1 .. $second_table_row_count],
            );
            $dbh->do($stmt, undef, @bind);
        }
    }
}

sub _run_sql {
    $children_dbh ||= dbi_connect();
    $children_dbh->selectall_arrayref(q{
        SELECT first.num
        FROM first
        LEFT JOIN second AS second_1 ON second_1.num = -1
        LEFT JOIN second AS second_2 ON second_2.num = -2
        LEFT JOIN second AS second_3 ON second_3.num = -3
        LEFT JOIN second AS second_4 ON second_4.num = -4
        LEFT JOIN second AS second_5 ON second_5.num = -5
        LEFT JOIN second AS second_6 ON second_6.num = -6
        WHERE second_1.num IS NULL
          AND second_2.num IS NULL
          AND second_3.num IS NULL
          AND second_4.num IS NULL
          AND second_5.num IS NULL
          AND second_6.num IS NULL
    });
}

sub dbi_connect {
    return DBI->connect(
        'dbi:mysql:'
            . 'database=tmp'
            . ';host=localhost'
            . ';port=3306',
        'root',
        '',
    );
}
```

And for compare queries like this executed in concurrent with increasing performance:

```
SELECT first.num
FROM first
LEFT JOIN second AS second_1 ON second_1.num = 1 # existent key
LEFT JOIN second AS second_2 ON second_2.num = 2 # existent key
LEFT JOIN second AS second_3 ON second_3.num = 3 # existent key
LEFT JOIN second AS second_4 ON second_4.num = 4 # existent key
LEFT JOIN second AS second_5 ON second_5.num = 5 # existent key
LEFT JOIN second AS second_6 ON second_6.num = 6 # existent key
WHERE second_1.num IS NOT NULL
  AND second_2.num IS NOT NULL
  AND second_3.num IS NOT NULL
  AND second_4.num IS NOT NULL
  AND second_5.num IS NOT NULL
  AND second_6.num IS NOT NULL
```

Testing results, cpu and disk usage measurements are here:

```
* table `first` have 1000 rows
* table `second` have 6 rows: `[1,1],[2,2],..[6,6]`

For query:
    SELECT first.num
    FROM first
    LEFT JOIN second AS second_1 ON second_1.num = -1 # non-existent key
    LEFT JOIN second AS second_2 ON second_2.num = -2 # non-existent key
    LEFT JOIN second AS second_3 ON second_3.num = -3 # non-existent key
    LEFT JOIN second AS second_4 ON second_4.num = -4 # non-existent key
    LEFT JOIN second AS second_5 ON second_5.num = -5 # non-existent key
    LEFT JOIN second AS second_6 ON second_6.num = -6 # non-existent key
    WHERE second_1.num IS NULL
      AND second_2.num IS NULL
      AND second_3.num IS NULL
      AND second_4.num IS NULL
      AND second_5.num IS NULL
      AND second_6.num IS NULL

Results:
    concurrency: 1,     speed: 162.910 / sec
    concurrency: 2,     speed: 137.818 / sec
    concurrency: 3,     speed: 130.728 / sec
    concurrency: 4,     speed: 107.387 / sec
    concurrency: 6,     speed: 90.513 / sec
    concurrency: 8,     speed: 80.445 / sec
    concurrency: 10,    speed: 80.381 / sec
    concurrency: 20,    speed: 84.069 / sec

System usage after for last 60 minutes of running query in 6 processes:
    $ iostat -cdkx 60

    avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
              74.82    0.00    0.08    0.00    0.08   25.02

    Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
    sda1              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.12     0.00     0.80    13.71     0.00    1.43   1.43   0.02
    sdf10             0.00     0.00    0.00    0.03     0.00     1.07    64.00     0.00   10.00   5.00   0.02
    sdf4              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.03     0.00     1.07    64.00     0.00   30.00  15.00   0.05
    sdm               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
    sdf8              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.37     0.00     1.24     6.77     0.00    5.00   3.18   0.12
    sdf6              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.03     0.00     1.07    64.00     0.00   10.00   5.00   0.02
    sdf9              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.03     0.00     1.07    64.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
    sdf               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
    sdf3              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.08     0.00     1.33    32.00     0.00    4.00   4.00   0.03
    sdf2              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.17     0.00     1.37    16.50     0.00    3.00   3.00   0.05
    sdf15             0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
    sdf14             0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
    sdf1              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.05     0.00     0.40    16.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
    sdf13             0.00     0.00    0.00    0.03     0.00     1.07    64.00     0.00   10.00   5.00   0.02
    sdf5              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.03     0.00     1.07    64.00     0.00   50.00  25.00   0.08
    sdm2              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
    sdm1              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
    sdf12             0.00     0.00    0.00    0.03     0.00     1.07    64.00     0.00   10.00   5.00   0.02
    sdf11             0.00     0.00    0.00    0.03     0.00     1.07    64.00     0.00   10.00   5.00   0.02
    sdf7              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.03     0.00     1.07    64.00     0.00   10.00   5.00   0.02
    md0               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.97     0.00    13.95    28.86     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00

################################################################################

For query:
    SELECT first.num
    FROM first
    LEFT JOIN second AS second_1 ON second_1.num = 1 # existent key
    LEFT JOIN second AS second_2 ON second_2.num = 2 # existent key
    LEFT JOIN second AS second_3 ON second_3.num = 3 # existent key
    LEFT JOIN second AS second_4 ON second_4.num = 4 # existent key
    LEFT JOIN second AS second_5 ON second_5.num = 5 # existent key
    LEFT JOIN second AS second_6 ON second_6.num = 6 # existent key
    WHERE second_1.num IS NOT NULL
      AND second_2.num IS NOT NULL
      AND second_3.num IS NOT NULL
      AND second_4.num IS NOT NULL
      AND second_5.num IS NOT NULL
      AND second_6.num IS NOT NULL

Results:
    concurrency: 1,     speed: 875.973 / sec
    concurrency: 2,     speed: 944.986 / sec
    concurrency: 3,     speed: 1256.072 / sec
    concurrency: 4,     speed: 1401.657 / sec
    concurrency: 6,     speed: 1354.351 / sec
    concurrency: 8,     speed: 1110.100 / sec
    concurrency: 10,    speed: 1145.251 / sec
    concurrency: 20,    speed: 1142.514 / sec

System usage after for last 60 minutes of running query in 6 processes:
    $ iostat -cdkx 60

    avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
              74.40    0.00    0.53    0.00    0.06   25.01

    Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
    sda1              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.02     0.00     0.13    16.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
    sdf10             0.00     0.00    0.00    0.03     0.00     1.07    64.00     0.00   10.00   5.00   0.02
    sdf4              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.03     0.00     1.07    64.00     0.00   10.00   5.00   0.02
    sdm               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
    sdf8              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.03     0.00     1.07    64.00     0.00   10.00   5.00   0.02
    sdf6              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.03     0.00     1.07    64.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
    sdf9              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.03     0.00     1.07    64.00     0.00   10.00   5.00   0.02
    sdf               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
    sdf3              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.13     0.00     2.67    40.00     0.00    3.75   2.50   0.03
    sdf2              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.23     0.00     2.72    23.29     0.00    2.14   1.43   0.03
    sdf15             0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
    sdf14             0.00     0.00    0.00    0.98     0.00     0.54     1.10     0.00    2.71   2.71   0.27
    sdf1              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.08     0.00     1.47    35.20     0.00    8.00   6.00   0.05
    sdf13             0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
    sdf5              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.03     0.00     1.07    64.00     0.00   10.00   5.00   0.02
    sdm2              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
    sdm1              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
    sdf12             0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
    sdf11             0.00     0.00    0.00    0.03     0.00     1.07    64.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
    sdf7              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.03     0.00     1.07    64.00     0.00   10.00   5.00   0.02
    md0               0.00     0.00    0.00    1.70     0.00    15.92    18.74     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00

################################################################################

And this server has lots of free memory. Example of top:
    top - 19:02:59 up  4:23,  4 users,  load average: 4.43, 3.03, 2.01
    Tasks: 218 total,   1 running, 217 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
    Cpu(s): 72.8%us,  0.7%sy,  0.0%ni, 26.3%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.1%st
    Mem:  71701416k total, 22183980k used, 49517436k free,      284k buffers
    Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,  1282768k cached

      PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
     2506 mysql     20   0 51.7g  17g 5920 S  590 25.8 213:15.12 mysqld
     9348 topadver  20   0 72256  11m 1428 S    2  0.0   0:01.45 perl
     9349 topadver  20   0 72256  11m 1428 S    2  0.0   0:01.44 perl
     9350 topadver  20   0 72256  11m 1428 S    2  0.0   0:01.45 perl
     9351 topadver  20   0 72256  11m 1428 S    1  0.0   0:01.44 perl
     9352 topadver  20   0 72256  11m 1428 S    1  0.0   0:01.44 perl
     9353 topadver  20   0 72256  11m 1428 S    1  0.0   0:01.44 perl
     9346 topadver  20   0 19340 1504 1064 R    0  0.0   0:01.89 top
```

Does anyone have an idea why performance decreased for query with non-existent keys?

Comment: why you use 'where num.... is null'  if your create table already has NOT NULL condition?

Comment: @jcho360 left joins will create nulls like that.  This seems like configuration.  Awayka, Could you give some information on your MYSQL server?  Does it have multiple processors?

Comment: @Twelfth mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.59, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1 on m2.4xlarge EC2 instance which has 8 cores

Comment: I'd recommend looking into what the load of non-CPU resources on your system looks like when not running this query vs. running one query vs. running multiple queries in parallel. Your query may be using a large amount of memory causing you to hit swap on multiple queries. Or you disk/disk bus/memory bus may be the bottle neck. If you can't feed the CPU's data fast enough parallel queries won't help.

Comment: @Ven'Tatsu As i can conclude from my measurements there is no bottleneck of such resources. There is big margin in memory - this is for sure. And similar, but slightly different queries performs as expected, I added this information above. I compared disk usage of cases with "good" queries and "bad" and see no difference. So if u can, read my results, may be u can find something, or give an advice what else and how i can measure.

Comment: @awayka Nice question (got my +1). Don't forget to accept an answer if this is now resolved.

Answer (score 8):

Well written question, that shows some research.

Out of curiosity, I tried MySQL 5.6 to see what the tooling there has to say about these queries.

First, note that the queries are different:

- changing the value from "1" to "-1" for the existent / non existent
  key case is one thing
- changing "second_1.num IS NOT NULL" to
  "second_1.num IS NULL" in the WHERE clause is another.

Using EXPLAIN  gives different plans:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT `first`.num
FROM `first`
LEFT JOIN `second` AS second_1 ON second_1.num = -1 # non-existent key
LEFT JOIN `second` AS second_2 ON second_2.num = -2 # non-existent key
LEFT JOIN `second` AS second_3 ON second_3.num = -3 # non-existent key
LEFT JOIN `second` AS second_4 ON second_4.num = -4 # non-existent key
LEFT JOIN `second` AS second_5 ON second_5.num = -5 # non-existent key
LEFT JOIN `second` AS second_6 ON second_6.num = -6 # non-existent key
WHERE second_1.num IS NULL
AND second_2.num IS NULL
AND second_3.num IS NULL
AND second_4.num IS NULL
AND second_5.num IS NULL
AND second_6.num IS NULL
;
id      select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len ref     rows    Extra
1       SIMPLE  first   index   NULL    key_num 4       NULL    1000    Using index
1       SIMPLE  second_1        ref     key_num key_num 4       const   1       Using where; Not exists; Using index
1       SIMPLE  second_2        ref     key_num key_num 4       const   1       Using where; Not exists; Using index
1       SIMPLE  second_3        ref     key_num key_num 4       const   1       Using where; Not exists; Using index
1       SIMPLE  second_4        ref     key_num key_num 4       const   1       Using where; Not exists; Using index
1       SIMPLE  second_5        ref     key_num key_num 4       const   1       Using where; Not exists; Using index
1       SIMPLE  second_6        ref     key_num key_num 4       const   1       Using where; Not exists; Using index
```

as opposed to

```
EXPLAIN SELECT `first`.num
FROM `first`
LEFT JOIN `second` AS second_1 ON second_1.num = 1 # existent key
LEFT JOIN `second` AS second_2 ON second_2.num = 2 # existent key
LEFT JOIN `second` AS second_3 ON second_3.num = 3 # existent key
LEFT JOIN `second` AS second_4 ON second_4.num = 4 # existent key
LEFT JOIN `second` AS second_5 ON second_5.num = 5 # existent key
LEFT JOIN `second` AS second_6 ON second_6.num = 6 # existent key
WHERE second_1.num IS NOT NULL
AND second_2.num IS NOT NULL
AND second_3.num IS NOT NULL
AND second_4.num IS NOT NULL
AND second_5.num IS NOT NULL
AND second_6.num IS NOT NULL
;
id      select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len ref     rows    Extra
1       SIMPLE  second_1        ref     key_num key_num 4       const   1       Using index
1       SIMPLE  second_2        ref     key_num key_num 4       const   1       Using index
1       SIMPLE  second_3        ref     key_num key_num 4       const   1       Using index
1       SIMPLE  second_4        ref     key_num key_num 4       const   1       Using index
1       SIMPLE  second_5        ref     key_num key_num 4       const   1       Using index
1       SIMPLE  second_6        ref     key_num key_num 4       const   1       Using index
1       SIMPLE  first   index   NULL    key_num 4       NULL    1000    Using index; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
```

Using the JSON format, we have:

```
EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT `first`.num
FROM `first`
LEFT JOIN `second` AS second_1 ON second_1.num = -1 # non-existent key
LEFT JOIN `second` AS second_2 ON second_2.num = -2 # non-existent key
LEFT JOIN `second` AS second_3 ON second_3.num = -3 # non-existent key
LEFT JOIN `second` AS second_4 ON second_4.num = -4 # non-existent key
LEFT JOIN `second` AS second_5 ON second_5.num = -5 # non-existent key
LEFT JOIN `second` AS second_6 ON second_6.num = -6 # non-existent key
WHERE second_1.num IS NULL
AND second_2.num IS NULL
AND second_3.num IS NULL
AND second_4.num IS NULL
AND second_5.num IS NULL
AND second_6.num IS NULL
;
EXPLAIN
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "nested_loop": [
      {
        "table": {
          "table_name": "first",
          "access_type": "index",
          "key": "key_num",
          "key_length": "4",
          "rows": 1000,
          "filtered": 100,
          "using_index": true
        }
      },
      {
        "table": {
          "table_name": "second_1",
          "access_type": "ref",
          "possible_keys": [
            "key_num"
          ],
          "key": "key_num",
          "key_length": "4",
          "ref": [
            "const"
          ],
          "rows": 1,
          "filtered": 100,
          "not_exists": true,
          "using_index": true,
          "attached_condition": "<if>(found_match(second_1), isnull(`test`.`second_1`.`num`), true)"
        }
      },
      {
        "table": {
          "table_name": "second_2",
          "access_type": "ref",
          "possible_keys": [
            "key_num"
          ],
          "key": "key_num",
          "key_length": "4",
          "ref": [
            "const"
          ],
          "rows": 1,
          "filtered": 100,
          "not_exists": true,
          "using_index": true,
          "attached_condition": "<if>(found_match(second_2), isnull(`test`.`second_2`.`num`), true)"
        }
      },
      {
        "table": {
          "table_name": "second_3",
          "access_type": "ref",
          "possible_keys": [
            "key_num"
          ],
          "key": "key_num",
          "key_length": "4",
          "ref": [
            "const"
          ],
          "rows": 1,
          "filtered": 100,
          "not_exists": true,
          "using_index": true,
          "attached_condition": "<if>(found_match(second_3), isnull(`test`.`second_3`.`num`), true)"
        }
      },
      {
        "table": {
          "table_name": "second_4",
          "access_type": "ref",
          "possible_keys": [
            "key_num"
          ],
          "key": "key_num",
          "key_length": "4",
          "ref": [
            "const"
          ],
          "rows": 1,
          "filtered": 100,
          "not_exists": true,
          "using_index": true,
          "attached_condition": "<if>(found_match(second_4), isnull(`test`.`second_4`.`num`), true)"
        }
      },
      {
        "table": {
          "table_name": "second_5",
          "access_type": "ref",
          "possible_keys": [
            "key_num"
          ],
          "key": "key_num",
          "key_length": "4",
          "ref": [
            "const"
          ],
          "rows": 1,
          "filtered": 100,
          "not_exists": true,
          "using_index": true,
          "attached_condition": "<if>(found_match(second_5), isnull(`test`.`second_5`.`num`), true)"
        }
      },
      {
        "table": {
          "table_name": "second_6",
          "access_type": "ref",
          "possible_keys": [
            "key_num"
          ],
          "key": "key_num",
          "key_length": "4",
          "ref": [
            "const"
          ],
          "rows": 1,
          "filtered": 100,
          "not_exists": true,
          "using_index": true,
          "attached_condition": "<if>(found_match(second_6), isnull(`test`.`second_6`.`num`), true)"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

as opposed to

```
EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT `first`.num
FROM `first`
LEFT JOIN `second` AS second_1 ON second_1.num = 1 # existent key
LEFT JOIN `second` AS second_2 ON second_2.num = 2 # existent key
LEFT JOIN `second` AS second_3 ON second_3.num = 3 # existent key
LEFT JOIN `second` AS second_4 ON second_4.num = 4 # existent key
LEFT JOIN `second` AS second_5 ON second_5.num = 5 # existent key
LEFT JOIN `second` AS second_6 ON second_6.num = 6 # existent key
WHERE second_1.num IS NOT NULL
AND second_2.num IS NOT NULL
AND second_3.num IS NOT NULL
AND second_4.num IS NOT NULL
AND second_5.num IS NOT NULL
AND second_6.num IS NOT NULL
;
EXPLAIN
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "nested_loop": [
      {
        "table": {
          "table_name": "second_1",
          "access_type": "ref",
          "possible_keys": [
            "key_num"
          ],
          "key": "key_num",
          "key_length": "4",
          "ref": [
            "const"
          ],
          "rows": 1,
          "filtered": 100,
          "using_index": true
        }
      },
      {
        "table": {
          "table_name": "second_2",
          "access_type": "ref",
          "possible_keys": [
            "key_num"
          ],
          "key": "key_num",
          "key_length": "4",
          "ref": [
            "const"
          ],
          "rows": 1,
          "filtered": 100,
          "using_index": true
        }
      },
      {
        "table": {
          "table_name": "second_3",
          "access_type": "ref",
          "possible_keys": [
            "key_num"
          ],
          "key": "key_num",
          "key_length": "4",
          "ref": [
            "const"
          ],
          "rows": 1,
          "filtered": 100,
          "using_index": true
        }
      },
      {
        "table": {
          "table_name": "second_4",
          "access_type": "ref",
          "possible_keys": [
            "key_num"
          ],
          "key": "key_num",
          "key_length": "4",
          "ref": [
            "const"
          ],
          "rows": 1,
          "filtered": 100,
          "using_index": true
        }
      },
      {
        "table": {
          "table_name": "second_5",
          "access_type": "ref",
          "possible_keys": [
            "key_num"
          ],
          "key": "key_num",
          "key_length": "4",
          "ref": [
            "const"
          ],
          "rows": 1,
          "filtered": 100,
          "using_index": true
        }
      },
      {
        "table": {
          "table_name": "second_6",
          "access_type": "ref",
          "possible_keys": [
            "key_num"
          ],
          "key": "key_num",
          "key_length": "4",
          "ref": [
            "const"
          ],
          "rows": 1,
          "filtered": 100,
          "using_index": true
        }
      },
      {
        "table": {
          "table_name": "first",
          "access_type": "index",
          "key": "key_num",
          "key_length": "4",
          "rows": 1000,
          "filtered": 100,
          "using_index": true,
          "using_join_buffer": "Block Nested Loop"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Looking at the table io instrumented by the performance schema at runtime, we have:

```
truncate table performance_schema.objects_summary_global_by_type;
select * from performance_schema.objects_summary_global_by_type
where OBJECT_NAME in ("first", "second");
OBJECT_TYPE OBJECT_SCHEMA   OBJECT_NAME COUNT_STAR  SUM_TIMER_WAIT  MIN_TIMER_WAIT  AVG_TIMER_WAIT  MAX_TIMER_WAIT
TABLE   test    first   0   0   0   0   0
TABLE   test    second  0   0   0   0   0
SELECT `first`.num
FROM `first`
LEFT JOIN `second` AS second_1 ON second_1.num = -1 # non-existent key
LEFT JOIN `second` AS second_2 ON second_2.num = -2 # non-existent key
LEFT JOIN `second` AS second_3 ON second_3.num = -3 # non-existent key
LEFT JOIN `second` AS second_4 ON second_4.num = -4 # non-existent key
LEFT JOIN `second` AS second_5 ON second_5.num = -5 # non-existent key
LEFT JOIN `second` AS second_6 ON second_6.num = -6 # non-existent key
WHERE second_1.num IS NULL
AND second_2.num IS NULL
AND second_3.num IS NULL
AND second_4.num IS NULL
AND second_5.num IS NULL
AND second_6.num IS NULL
;
(...)
select * from performance_schema.objects_summary_global_by_type
where OBJECT_NAME in ("first", "second");
OBJECT_TYPE OBJECT_SCHEMA   OBJECT_NAME COUNT_STAR  SUM_TIMER_WAIT  MIN_TIMER_WAIT  AVG_TIMER_WAIT  MAX_TIMER_WAIT
TABLE   test    first   1003    5705014442  1026171 5687889 87356557
TABLE   test    second  6012    271786533972    537266  45207298    1123939292
```

as opposed to:

```
select * from performance_schema.objects_summary_global_by_type
where OBJECT_NAME in ("first", "second");
OBJECT_TYPE OBJECT_SCHEMA   OBJECT_NAME COUNT_STAR  SUM_TIMER_WAIT  MIN_TIMER_WAIT  AVG_TIMER_WAIT  MAX_TIMER_WAIT
TABLE   test    first   1003    5211074603  969338  5195454 61066176
TABLE   test    second  24  458656783   510085  19110361    66229860
```

The query that scales does almost no table IO in table `second`.
The query that does not scale does 6K table IO in table `second`, or 6 times the size of table `first`.

This is because the query plans are different, in turn because the queries are different (IS NOT NULL versus IS NULL).

I think that answers the performance related question.

Note that both queries returned 1000 rows in my tests, which may not be what you want.
Before tuning a query to make it faster, make sure it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest trying an approach where each `fork` uses its own connection (it looks to me that right now `$children_dbh`, which holds a DB connection, is a shared variable). Or, even better, implement so-called `connection pool`, from which each client process will take a connection at a time when it's required, and will 'give it back' when it's no longer needed.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1482192/1229023) for further details: the thread where it was given is about Java, but it's actually about some universal principles of MySQL organization. And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455190/how-to-access-mysql-from-multiple-threads-concurrently) might be useful as well.

P.S. Somewhat similar situation (I think) is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127229/perl-parallelforkmanager-with-dbi-database-handlers), and there's a detailed explanation of how to organize a connection pool.

Comment: What will this string `$children_dbh ||= dbi_connect();` of `_run_sql()` do?

Comment: Looks like there are no threads to me: single thread for each process. Where did you see threads? [Parallel::Benchmark](http://search.cpan.org/~fujiwara/Parallel-Benchmark-0.04/lib/Parallel/Benchmark.pm) uses [Parallel::ForkManager](http://search.cpan.org/~dlux/Parallel-ForkManager-0.7.9/lib/Parallel/ForkManager.pm) which forks.

Comment: My point is that there's a shared connection, which explains why performance actually becomes worse with each new process. And, I say it again, it's quite easy to check how many connections to DB are actually used. It's no point saying 'looks like' and debating about the theory: either a single connection is used - or not.

Comment: It forks before creating connection, so each process gets independent connection.

Comment: @raina77ow Raina, I'm sorry to be the one to say it, but this answer has actually nothing to do with the question. If it is not clear from the source that there is NO shared connection one can just copy/paste and run the code to get it.